# Amazon CloudFront not consistently returning 304 (Not Modified) for unchanged static content?

Tags: asp.net, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

A grid of EC2 web servers is running behind an ELB load balancer. The ELB is behind Amazon's CloudFront content delivery network. Content Delivery Networks are very new to me. My understanding is that CloudFront is supposed to speed up performance by caching static content at its "edges". But this isn't what's happening.

Consider my EC2 instances whose content should always have a lifetime of five minutes. For static content this usually means declaring the following in my web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00.00:05:00"/>
</staticContent>
```

...and for the dynamic stuff, it usually means executing the following commands against an HttpResponse object:

```
resp.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
resp.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

With that as background...

**When my browser hits the ELB directly**, everything works as expected. Firebug consistently shows that 304 (Not Modified) is returned for content that exists in the browser's cache, has passed its five minute expiration, but has not been changed on the server. Here are the response headers for a download of defs.js, for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public,max-age=300
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 13:54:16 GMT
Etag: "0152435d158cf1:0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 17:36:18 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Connection: keep-alive
```

IIS correctly sees that the file hasn't been changed since April 15th and returns 304.

But looks what happens **when the file is grabbed through CloudFront**.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Length: 205
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public,max-age=300
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 14:07:33 GMT
Etag: "0152435d158cf1:0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 17:36:18 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Age: 16
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0f140ef1be762325ad24a7167aa57e65.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Evfdhs-pxFojnzkQWuG-Ubp6B2TC5xbunhavG8ivXURdp2fw_noXjw==
```

In this case CloudFront forces the browser to download the entire file again even though, as you can see:

(a) it knows the file hasn't been modified since April 15th (see Last-Modified header), and
(b) CloudFront does have a cached copy of the file on hand (see X-Cache header)

Perhaps you're wondering if my browser is sending a valid If-Modified-Since header. Indeed it is. Here are the request headers:

```
GET /code/shared/defs.js HTTP/1.1
Host: d2fn6fv5a0cu3b.cloudfront.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://d2fn6fv5a0cu3b.cloudfront.net/
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 17:36:18 GMT
If-None-Match: "0152435d158cf1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

It's an odd situation. If I just sit in front of my browser and keep doing page Reloads (Cmd-R), maybe about half the time CloudFront will correctly return a 304 and the other half of the time it'll incorrectly return 200 along with all of the content. Waiting for the five minute expiration before interacting with the page yields primarily 200's and only a few 304's. This odd behavior applies to all of the files (.css, .js, .png, etc.) referenced on the HTML page as well as for the containing HTML page itself. I know my app is coded properly because as mentioned above, hitting the ELB directly without going through CloudFront results in the expected 304 result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer was found in an obscure sentence written in a seemingly unrelated piece of Amazon documentation:

`When you configure CloudFront to forward cookies to your origin [...] If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match conditional requests are not supported.`

Strange, but indeed the reality of the situation is far worse; It's not that forwarding cookies to your origin servers disables conditional requests, but rather that is disables them *sometimes* -- to the point where the HTTP result code (304 vs 200) is virtually random.

It's important to note that you'll be bitten by this bizarre behavior **even if you're not using cookies at all**. It's still absolutely essential that the Forward Cookies drop-down be set to "None" as shown in the image below:

[image]

Switching the setting to "None" fixes the errant behavior described in my original post.

This solution presents you with another problem though. You're telling CloudFront to totally strip out all cookies prior to forwarding the request to your origin. But your origin server might *need* those cookies. Further, if you're using the ELB (load balancer) as your origin, a critical cookie that the ELB depends upon to maintain sticky sessions will be totally dropped. Not good.

The solution to the cookie-stripping problem will depend on how your site is organized. In my case, transmission of cookies (session-related or otherwise) is only necessary when posting AJAX data to `myDomain.com/ajax/`. Because all cookie-dependent URLs fall under the category of `ajax/*` , a new behavioral rule for that path had to be created and in that rule, and that rule only, the Forward Cookies drop-down is set to "All" instead of "None."

So there it is. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Goddamn AWS, now I'll need to switch from cookie based auth to JWT. >:( Many thanks to you!